# When to override dark mode in Activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-darkmode

I'm trying to adopt best practice for managing light and dark mode in my app, based on guidance [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme/) and [here](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark/).

Based on this, I am using a theme inherited from `DayNight`:

In Manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
</application>
```

In themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorButtonNormal</item>
</style>
```

This has the desired effect of opening up an Activity in a light or dark theme, based on the device's system setting.

But I want to give the user the option of overriding the mode, e.g. to be always dark (even if the system is in light mode).

But when the system is in light mode, I'm finding that that my Activity initially opens up with a light theme (flash of white), before I get the chance to switch over to the dark theme.  I'm switching as soon as I possibly can in the Activity lifecycle:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
```

But even then, I'm getting an annoying "flash of light" before the Activity switches over to dark.

How do I avoid the flash of light?

Answer (score 2):

I took some teaching from [this project](https://github.com/NUmeroAndDev/MaterialGallery-android) about how to do things properly.

What they do in the sample app above is to specify a single theme in the Manifest, but cunningly that theme is overridden in the `night` variant of the theme:

In `src/main/res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Base.MaterialGallery" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    ... some base styling ...
</style>

<style name="Theme.MaterialGallery" parent="Base.MaterialGallery">
    ... styling specific to LIGHT theme ...
</style>

<style name="Theme.MaterialGallery.DayNight" parent="Theme.MaterialGallery" />
```

The last one above is what is set in the Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MaterialGalleryApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialGallery.DayNight"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Cunningly, the `DayNight` theme is overridden for dark mode in `src/main/res/values-night/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MaterialGallery.DayNight" parent="Theme.MaterialGallery">
    ... styling specific to DARK theme (since we're in the NIGHT values-night/themes.xml ...
</style>
```

By specifying the `DayNight` theme in the Manifest, you get the right theme straight away when the Activity starts, with no messing around.